# Are PayPal cookies linked to an IP address?

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I have been experimenting with curl for accessing the PayPal payment authorisation site using PHP.

e.g.

```
...
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $res = curl_exec ($ch);

   preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie: .*/', $res, $cookieMatches);

   foreach ($cookieMatches[0] as $cookieMatch)
      header($cookieMatch);

   preg_match('/Location: .*/', $res, $locMatches);
   header($locMatches[0]);

   header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
   header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=500');
   header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
   header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

The principle being simply to reflect the original redirect (I am sure there is a simpler way to do this).  However, the response from PayPal seems to indicate some kind of cookie error.

My hunch is that the cookie has been linked to the originating machine in some way.  Can anyone confirm this, or am I just missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0):

The CURL has built-in support for cookies (as you know). But it's been tricky. I haven't managed cookies to work until I declared option

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

Third parameter is a name of the file storing cookies - preferably in temp folder. Maybe you should just try this approach.

With this the redirects work "automatically".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - and also CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE should be set.  I tried this approach initially but the PayPal billing details or log in submission forms then fail.  In comparison with a direct HTML form submission, a number of cookies seem to be missing from the browser.  An HTTP sniffer confirmed this - which is why I tried the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
//SAVE THE COOKIES
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
USE THE COOKIES
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1');
// Follow Where the location will take you, maybe you catch the issue.
```

Since it's working on browser it has to work using CURL, unless they are using javascript to set cookies.
even if they are using cookies depending on IP address, try to start the session from beginning using curl so they set your server ip address with generated cookies.